# How to execute useEffect every time outlet changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Here's my code in react:

```
function ProtectedRoutes(props) {

    useEffect(() => {

        setTimeout(props.verify_access, 100)

    }, [])

    const { isAuth } = props
    
    if(isAuth){

        return <Outlet />
    }else{

        return <Navigate to={"/login"}/>
    }

}


const mapStateToProps  = state => {

    return {
        isAuth: state.auth.isAuthenticated
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { verify_access })(ProtectedRoutes)
```

So what's going on here is that I'm trying to make a protected routes for authenticated users only.  I'm authenticating users with JWT stored in `localStorage` and I need the redux action `props.verify_access` to check for the JWT every time user goes to a different page. As you can probably see by now, that's not gonna happen because apparently the the `useEffect` hook will only  run when the parent route is first initialized, if I go to any route inside the parent route the `useEffect` will not do anything. I tried to put in `Outlet` in the `useEffect` array but it doesn't work

How do I execute `useEffect` every time the user loads a new Protected Routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `useLocation` hook to access the `location` object and use the `pathname` as a dependency for the `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProtectedRoutes({ isAuth, verify_access }) {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(verify_access, 100);
  }, [location.pathname, verify_access]);

  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-execute-useeffect-every-time-outlet-changes]